# Dio is making a lot of request when debugging with debugger

Tags: flutter, networking, dio

I am debugging the API call to server for authentication. When I debug in Android Studio and step into the request, network shows multiple requests being made. While not debugging, the request are happening only once, but during debugging with breakpoints, there are mutltitude of requests being made.

These are the base options and interceptors being used. The interceptor also confirms that multiple requests are being made for some reason.

```dart
 Dio get dio => Dio(BaseOptions(
        baseUrl:
            '${getIt<ConfigReader>().baseURL}${getIt<ConfigReader>().apiPath}',
        contentType: Headers.jsonContentType,
        responseType: ResponseType.json,
        headers: {
          'Accept': Headers.jsonContentType,
        },
      ))
        ..interceptors.add(LogInterceptor());
```

[image]

How can I resolve the issue?